# Is it better to programmatically draw or use .9.pngs for simple shapes?

Tags: android, drawable, draw, nine-patch

Would it be quicker in loadtime to draw programmatically or use a 9-patch image for simple shapes such as a  10dp flat colour line to designate a selected tab on nav drawer and to colour the entire action bar?

I want to also be able to set these colours via the user settings (so that they could enter a hex code and change the colour of the action bar and other assets) if possible.

Comment: Unless you are going to use this for views that are all over the screen, and you have a list view or scroll view that's going to force a lot of continuous redraws, there is going to be no human-perceivable difference.